# nautilus: g_time_val_from_iso8601: assertion 'iso_date != NULL' failed

Tags: nautilus, files, 22.04

Recent upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04, and my /var/log/syslog is being flooded with:

```
nautilus[103320]: g_time_val_from_iso8601: assertion 'iso_date != NULL' failed
```

Anybody have any idea what to look for to fix this?

Comment: I've found this https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/2160. Seems to be a regression in autilus introdiced in Gnome 42.

Comment: @LorenzKeel Thanks!